# About CS50 pset2 vigenere

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

Why my code would not skip the space and it led to wrong encryption sequence?

When I check with an example "Hello, World!", my code counted the space also and converted to "Iekmo, Wnslc!" instead of "Iekmo, Vprke!" using the key "baz"

Can someone explain the logic behind? Many thanks!

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//getting user encryption key


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./vigenere keyword\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //check if all are alphabeticals
    else 
    {
           for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < strlen(argv[i]); j++)
            {
                if (isalpha(argv[i][j]) == false)
                {                
                    printf("Usage: ./vigenere keyword\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }  


    //getting plaintext divide it into each character
    string pt = get_string("plaintext: ");

    printf("ciphertext: ");
    //convert to ciphertext
    //C = (P + k) % 26
    for (int r = 0; r < strlen(pt); r++)
    {                           
        if (isupper(pt[r]))
        {
            //making loop with j group corresponding to keyword
            int j = r % strlen(argv[1]);
            int key = tolower(argv[1][j]) - 97;
            printf("%c", (pt[r] - 65 + key) % 26 + 65);
        }
        else if (islower(pt[r]))
        {
            //making loop with j group corresponding to keyword
            int j = r % strlen(argv[1]);
            int key = tolower(argv[1][j]) - 97;
            printf("%c", (pt[r] - 97 + key) % 26 + 97);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", pt[r]);
        }

     }            
       printf("\n");       

}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger to see where it's going wrong?

Comment: It's a good idea to report errors on the `stderr` (standard error) stream.  You can avoid calling `strlen()` on each iteration by replacing `for (int j = 0; j < strlen(argv[i]); j++)` with `for (int j = 0; argv[i][j] != '\0'; j++)` (and some people wouldn't write the `!= '\0'` out in full like that).  Neither of these directly affect the correctness of the code, though.  You should use `'a'` and `'A'` instead of 97 and 65; that makes the code more readable and more easily comprehended.

Comment: You need to separate 'position in string `r`' from 'encrypted character number'.  You need an extra variable that you only increment when the character is alphabetic.

Comment: _Side note:_ for your first `if` it does a `return`. So, you can eliminate the `else` on that and just outdent the code. That is, `if (whatever) return; else { do_stuff }` goes to `if (whatever) return; do_stuff`

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler
Thank you for your comments.
But I still can't figure it out how to increment only when it is alphabetic
I can only think of a for loop to do so, but it is not applicable in defining the key and to use it in the printf. 
Can you tell me how to tackle the problem?

Comment: Don't use magic numbers. The code of the letter `a` is spelled this way: **`'a'`**.

Comment: Offtopic: Due to `argc != 2` in the `if` branch, you don't need the outer loop in the `else` one, it will be run one single time anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the calculation of j here `int j = r % strlen(argv[1]);`. The index of the key is not related to `r` (the index of the message). Program needs to iterate through the key based solely on (length of) the key. You need to increment it each time you "use" a key index, and "wrap" it so it doesn't go past the end. You might consider declaring `j` before the `r` loop; increment j whenever you use a key index (hint: `j++`); and "wrap" j with modulo operator (hint: `j % strlen(argv[1]`). I leave the actual code to you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.
I have figured it out now.
Appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot easier to show than explain:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s keyword\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; argv[i][j] != '\0'; j++)
        {
            if (isalpha(argv[i][j]) == false)
            {                
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: non-alphabetic character '%c' (%d) in key\n",
                        argv[0], argv[i][j], argv[i][j]);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    string pt = get_string("plaintext:  ");

    printf("ciphertext: ");
    int k = 0;
    int keylen = strlen(argv[1]);
    for (int r = 0; pt[r] != '\0'; r++)
    {                           
        if (isupper(pt[r]))
        {
            int j = k++ % keylen;
            int key = tolower(argv[1][j]) - 'a';
            printf("%c", (pt[r] - 'A' + key) % 26 + 'A');
        }
        else if (islower(pt[r]))
        {
            int j = k++ % keylen;
            int key = tolower(argv[1][j]) - 'a';
            printf("%c", (pt[r] - 'a' + key) % 26 + 'a');
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", pt[r]);
        }

     }            
     printf("\n");       
     return 0;
}
```

Example run:

```
$ ./vig89 baz
plaintext:  Hello, World!
ciphertext: Iekmo, Vprke!
$
```

As I noted in a comment, you need to separate 'position in string, `r`' from 'encrypted character number'. You need an extra variable that you only increment when the character is alphabetic.

In the code above, `k` is the extra variable (`keylen` is another, but it simply records the length of the key rather than repeatedly calling `strlen()`).  The value in `k` is incremented when it is known that the character is a letter and not otherwise.

I observe that it might be sensible to process `argv[1]` so that you don't have to do the `tolower()` conversion each time; you could do that while validating the keyword.

I've also reported errors on standard error, and not used `strlen()` in the condition part of the loops.  While the cost is not prohibitive if you're dealing with 3-letter keys, if you start calculating the length of a string that's 20 KiB long on each iteration, you might start to spot the overhead (unless the compiler manages to optimize it away — it might, it might not).  I've also aligned the plain text and the cipher text in the I/O.

There are quite a lot of other changes that could/should be made.  For example, the first `for (int i = 1; …)` loop is not needed; you only have one argument so you only need the inner `for (int j = 0; …)` loop.  It is also more idiomatic to use `if (!isalpha(argv[i][j]))` than to compare the result with `false`, especially since the [`isalpha`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4.1p1) macro is not guaranteed to return 0 or 1 (it returns zero or non-zero) – so changing `if (isalpha(argv[i][j]) == false)` to `if (isalpha(argv[i][j] != true)` would not be reliable.  I'd probably create a simple variable `char *key = argv[1];` (or `string key = argv[1];` in the context of CS50, though I'm not convinced that the CS50 `typedef char *string;` is a good idea) and use that in the program.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!
Now I get it. I have been struggling the reason behind for couple of days, really appreciate your detailed explanations.